# Line Class stuck on a few methods for java

Tags: java

Implement a class "Line" with istance fields x1, y1, x2, y2, slope, yIntercept, and slopeDefined. I have four methods included in my code as well. I have to implement the following methods.

`public boolean intersects(Line L2)`, `public boolean equals(Line L2)`, `public boolean isParalell(Line, L2)`

```
public class LineClass {

    double x1, y1, x2, y2;
    double yIntercept;
    boolean slopeDefined;

    // slope and point
    public LineClass(double s, double xOne, double yOne) {
        x1 = xOne;
        y1 = yOne;
        slope = s;
    }

    // two points
    public LineClass(double xOne, double yOne, double xTwo, double yTwo) {
        x1 = xOne;
        x2 = xTwo;
        y1 = yOne;
        y2 = yTwo;
    }

    // slope and y- intercept
    public LineClass(double s, double y) {
        slope = s;
        yIntercept = y;
    }

    // vertical line, x-intercept
    public LineClass(double xOne) {
        x1 = xOne;
    }

    // returns true if Line this intersects Line L2, false otherwise
    public boolean intersects(LineClass L2) {
        if (this.slope != L2.slope)
            slopeDefined = true;
        else
            slopeDefined = false;
        return slopeDefined;
    }

    // returns true if Line this is the same as Line L2, false otherwise
    public boolean equals(LineClass L2) {
        if (this.slopeDefined == L2.slope) && (this.)

    }
}
```

The problem is for `public boolean equals`, what method do I use? Because when I use `if(this.slopeDefined == L2.slope)` it does not work

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: What you are asking is not clear. How you determine whether lines are equal?

Comment: The four constructors given determine if the two lines are equal. And then I am supposed to use a boolean to return a true or false if Line = L2. But i am not sure how.

Comment: Does your code even compile before you try implementing `equals`? I don't see a declaration of `slope` anywhere.

Comment: Actually, why are you concerned about slope in the equals method? Wouldn't two lines that are equal have the same `x1`, `x2`, etc? You could compare those.

Comment: No it does not. It says to create a constant slope, but I am not sure if that is right.

Comment: Your code is kind of a mess. Do you understand the concepts you're modelling? E.g. Your `intersects` method doesn't make any sense in terms of geometry. I suggest you make sure you know what it means for a line to have a defined slope, etc.

Comment: I understand the constructors I created, but I do not understand the boolean methods

Comment: Your constructors do not appear to be working, though. I would say step 1 is to get your code to compile without adding intersects or equals etc. Then worry about adding the boolean methods, one at a time, and test each one after you add it to make sure it works.

Comment: Okay, I will try and do that. It has worked so far, but I cannot input anything into my console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't declared all of your variables, and your equals method is incomplete.

add this:

> double slope;

and this:

> // returns true if Line this is the same as Line L2, false otherwise
>
> public boolean equals(LineClass L2) {
>
> if (L2.slope == slope && L2.yIntercept == yIntercept)
>
> ```
>    return true;
> ```
>
> else
>
> ```
>    return false;
> ```
>
> }

This assumes that you are simply checking if the lines are mathematically equivalent.

Comment: okay. This makes more sense. So then, how would you create a method using the same concept with public boolean isParallel(Line, L2)?

Comment: You would simply check that the slopes are equal.

Comment: okay. Thank you. I would compare Line.slope == slope && L2.slope == slope?

Comment: A line that has the same slope, but has different x1,y1 and x2,y2 is a different line.

Comment: Yes, but same slope + same x/y intercept is the same line. Same slope is just parallel. And if it is in a method within the class, it would be:    if(L2.slope==slope)

Comment: yes but if you are comparing whether Line and L2 are parallel you would need two line objects. Therefore wouldnt it be, if (Line.slope == L2.slope)?

Comment: Two objects, yes, but it only takes one line in as an argument. The other line is the one from which the method is being called.
Example:
`
Line line1 = new Line(1,2,3,4);
Line line2 = new Line(2,4,6,8);

if(line1.equals(line2))
System.out.println("These lines are equal.")
`

Comment: Oh okay. I understand now. Am I allowed to respond with a thank you? (sorry I am pretty new to stackoverflow)

Comment: Woops, make that: if(line1.isParallel(line2))

Comment: No worries, so am I - besides, this being my first answer on here, I can now vote on posts, so win/win

Answer (score 0):

```
// returns true if Line this is the same as Line L2, false otherwise
public boolean equals(LineClass L2) {
    return x1 == L2.x1 &&
           x2 == L2.x2 &&
           y1 == L2.y1 &&
           y2 == L2.y2 && 
           slopeDefined == L2.slopeDefined &&
           yIntercept == L2.yIntercept;
}
```

This will return true if all the values of the variables in both `LineClass` objects are the same.